# Facebook thumbnails doesn't work

Tags: facebook

After moving to wordpress with a new theme my facebook updates can't have thumbnails.
www.dirtysoundwaves.net
I wonder about if the problem is because of the site?
Also tried some plugins for to fix the problem but they didn't work.
So I wonder about if someone have a solution?
Any codes to input for to specifies images?

Comment: I see thumbnails for the Facebook plugin under the likebox...

Comment: @nmagerko try to share a post,it wont show any thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `<head>` you have defined the OpenGraph tags 3 times, one of the `og:image` properties is empty and the other one has a URL in it (that's how it should be). I guess Facebook takes the first `og:image` property which is empty. If you're using multiple plugins for that at once try to disable them, except the "Fix Facebook Like WordPress Plugin", it outputs everything correctly.

```
<!-- Easy Facebook Share Thumbnails --><!-- Post type using default image -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Dirty Soundwaves"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://dirtysoundwaves.net"/>
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Dirty Soundwaves"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Bringing you the newest house, dance, trance, electro, dance, EDM music both from big and small DJs!"/>
<link rel="image_src" href=""/>
<!-- Easy Facebook Share Thumbnails -->


<!-- AddThis Button Begin -->
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_product = 'wpp-262';
var addthis_config = {"data_track_clickback":true,"data_track_addressbar":false};if (typeof(addthis_share) == "undefined"){ addthis_share = [];}</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4eb47d09009c0e94"></script><!-- Begin Fix Facebook Like WordPress Plugin -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Dirty Soundwaves"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="blog"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://dirtysoundwaves.net"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://dirtysoundwaves.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/do43k54-1024x156.png"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Dirty Soundwaves"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100002756869275"/>
<!-- End Fix Facebook Like WordPress Plugin -->
<!-- HeadSpace SEO 3.6.37 by John Godley - urbangiraffe.com -->
<!-- HeadSpace -->
<meta property='og:type' content='blog' />
<meta property='og:title' content='Dirty Soundwaves' />
<meta property='og:url' content='http://dirtysoundwaves.net' />
<meta property='og:site_name' content='Dirty Soundwaves' />
<meta property='og:locale' content='en_US' />
```

Comment: Thanks björn! Now when I try to get rid of this plugin ''Easy Facebook Share Thumbnails'', my site goes white and nothing else shows.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest debugging the og:url tags using http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=dirtysoundwaves.net

You can add/remove/reorganize them until you get no errors and no warnings and all of your tags are read correctly...including the image tag.